# Why is a delay(1) necessary before Wire.requestFrom?

Tags: i2c

I had a problem communicating an nodeMCU with an Arduino Pro Mini with I2C.

To find the culprit, I finally wrote an Echo Server in Arduino: it receives a byte and responds the same byte. In the nodeMCU I wrote a test program: it sends bytes to the Echo Server and verifies the response, in addition to any error conditions in the `Wire` methods.

Both processors are connected GND-GND, VCC-VCC, SDA-SDA and SCL-SCL. SDA and SCL have 10K pull-up resistors. Both are connected via USB to my PC, and I have two serial monitors to trace the execution.

In the tester program line 38 there is a `delay(1)`. If you comment it out, some `requestFrom()` fails randomly with return value != 1, but the Echo Server still received the byte.

As ATmega328 included TWI in the silicon, I can't understand what is failing here and why `delay(1)` seems to solve the problem. What I'm missing here?

**The tester program**

```
/*
 * Echo Server Test
 * Send one byte to the Echo Server and read it back.
 * Do it for bytes from 0x01 to 0xDD
 */
#include <Wire.h>

#define SLAVE_ADDRESS  42
byte car = 1; // car to be send to the Echo Server.

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);
  // We have a nodeMCU con I2C on pins D5 and D6.
    Wire.begin(D5, D6);
    delay(1000);
  Serial.println("");
    Serial.println(" Echo Server Tester");
    Serial.println("---------------------");
    Serial.println("###  Sent   Received");
    delay(1000);    
}

/*
 * Send one byte in each loop().
 */
void loop() {
    byte status;

    if(car > 0) {
        do {
            Wire.beginTransmission(SLAVE_ADDRESS);
            int written = Wire.write(car);
            status = Wire.endTransmission();

            switch(status) {
            case 0:
        delay(1); // Comment this out and watch requestFrom() fails.
                if(Wire.requestFrom(SLAVE_ADDRESS, 1) == 1) {
                    byte r = Wire.read();
                    printChar(car, r);
                    car++;
                } else {
                    Serial.println("error in return");
                    status = 4;
                }

                break;

            case 1:
                Serial.println("Data too long");
                break;

            case 2:
                Serial.println("NACK on address");
                break;

            case 3:
                Serial.println("NACK on data");
                break;

            case 4:
                Serial.println("Some error");
                break;
            }
        }

        while(status != 0);
    }
}

/*
 * Utility: print in bytes sent and received 
 */
void printChar(byte s, byte r) {
    Serial.print(s);
    Serial.print(" ");
    printBits(s);
    Serial.print(' ');
    printBits(r);

    if(r != s) {
    //  Mark invalid responses.
        Serial.print(" *");
    }

    Serial.println();
}

/*
 * Print a simple byte in binary
 */
void printBits(int car) {
    byte bit = 0x80;

    for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        int digit = car & bit;
        Serial.print(digit ? '1' : '0');
        bit >>= 1;
    }
}
```

**The Echo Server program**

```
/*
 * I2C Echo Server
 * Receive one byte from Master, echo the same byte to Master.
 */
#define MY_ADDRESS  42

#include <Wire.h>

volatile byte received;
volatile int count = 0;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);

  Wire.begin(MY_ADDRESS);
  Serial.println("--- Echo Server ---");

  Wire.onReceive(receiveCommand);
  Wire.onRequest(sendAnswer);
}

void loop() {
  static int lastCount = 0;

  if (count != lastCount) {
    Serial.print(lastCount + 1); Serial.print(" ");
    printChar(received);
    lastCount++;
  }
}

/*  
 * Receive a byte from Master  
 */
void receiveCommand(int howMany) {
  received = Wire.read();
  count++;
}

/* 
 * Send a byte to Master 
 */
void sendAnswer() {
  Wire.write(received);
}

/*
 * Utility print byte received/sent
 */
void printChar(byte car) {
  Serial.print("Char ");
  byte bit = 0x80;
  for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    byte digit = car & bit;
    Serial.print(digit ? '1' : '0');
    bit >>= 1;
  }
  Serial.println();
}
```

Comment: the TWI interface needs to wait a whole cycle before it requests again, otherwise the clock and buffer can get messed up.

Comment: THIS fixed my I2C problems, delay(1) I had not seen this mentioned anywhere previously, so thanks for the question and the answers as I have been going in circles why my first 2 reads worked but not my second read 2, although commenting out the first 2 reads then let the second 2 behave correctly. I will now find out the clock cycle and change delay(1) to a micros delay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 1 millisecond is not needed, try delayMicroseconds with 50 or maybe 20 µs.

The Arduino as a slave is totally different than for example a sensor. The Arduino as a slave uses a combination of hardware and software. The onRequest and onReceive functions are executed while the Arduino keeps the SCL line low. That is called clock pulse stretching.

With an Arduino **Uno** (ATmega328P microcontroller) connected to an Arduino Uno, this delay problem between a write and read on the I2C bus existed for a long time. A few years ago it was solved. It was a bug, a real bug. That delay is no longer needed.
There are still ways to make it unreliable, for example by disabling the interrupts for too long in the slave.

I read that is still exists with the Arduino **Due**. With the Due as a master and for example an ATmega328P (at 3.3V) as a slave, the Due still needs a delay.

The **nodeMCU** and the Raspberry Pi might still have some problems when an Arduino is used as a slave. The Arduino as a slave should at least run at 3.3V or a I2C level shifter should be used.
I don't know if the nodeMCU Wire library supports clock pulse stretching.
That delay might still be needed. Even then, I don't know how reliable the communication will be.

The Wire.endTransmission is the function that transmits the data (not the Wire.write). If that is followed too soon by a Wire.requestFrom and there is a bug in the Wire library, that can cause troubles.